# How to remove the last word in a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the last word in the string using JavaScript?

For example, the string is "I want to remove the last word."

After using removal, the string in the textbox will display "I want to remove the last"

I've seen how to remove the last character using the *substring* function, but because the last word can be different every time. Is there a way to count how many words are required to remove in JavaScript?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use:

```
var str = "I want to remove the last word.";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");

str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
```

Get the last space and then get the substring.

Comment: This is a great solution. It works for me, and I'm going to enhance it.

Comment: It only works with string without line breaks. Otherwise choose @abePdIta solution.

Answer (score 23):

An easy way to do that would be to use JavaScript's [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) methods:

```
var myString = "I want to remove the last word";
myString = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do a simple regular expression like so:

```
"I want to remove the last word.".replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, '')
>>> "I want to remove the last"
```

Finding the last index for `" "` is probably faster though. This is just less code.

Answer (score 8):

Following [answer](/a/9323309/7600034) by [Amir Raminfar](/users/419075), I found this solution. In my opinion, it's better than accepted answer, because it works even if you have a space at the end of the string or with languages (like French) that have spaces between last word and punctuation mark.

```
"Je veux supprimer le dernier    mot !".replace(/[\W]*\S+[\W]*$/, '')
"Je veux supprimer le dernier"
```

It strips also the space(s) and punctuation marks before the last word, as the OP implicitly required.

Peace.

Answer (score 4):

Fooling around just for fun, this is a funny and outrageous way to do it!

```
"I want to remove the last word.".split(" ").reverse().slice(1).reverse().join(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `split` function:

```
var myString = "I want to remove the last word";
var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");
var lastWord =  mySplitResult[mySplitResult.length-1]
```

Comment: This one is also work for me to retrieve the last word in the string. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't fulfill the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer to this question would be as below,

```
var str="I want to remove the last word".split(' ');
var lastword=str.pop();
console.log(str.join(' '));
```

Comment: Your string is too long for the example :P

Comment: Just a pity that it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the last word following a space that has no word characters following it.

```
word=/s+\W*([a-zA-Z']+)\W*$/.exec(string);
if(word) alert(word[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else here is trying to split a string name in to last name and first name, please make sure to handle the case in which the name has only word.

`let recipientName = _.get(response, 'shipping_address.recipient_name');
 let lastWordIndex = recipientName.lastIndexOf(" ");
 let firstName = (lastWordIndex == -1) ? recipientName : recipientName.substring(0, lastWordIndex);
 let lastName = (lastWordIndex == -1) ? '' : recipientName.substring(lastWordIndex + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

To get the last word

```
const animals = "I want to remove the last word.".split(" ");
console.log(animals.slice(-1));
```

Expected output: word.

To remove the last word

```
console.log(animals.slice(0, -1).join(" ");
```

Expected output: "I want to remove the last"