# How can I remove the last word from a string?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I remove the last word from a string?

For example, with this input:  `"I am from Tamil Nadu."`

I want this result:  `"I am from Tamil."`

Comment: you could do this easily enough without jquery though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323182/how-to-remove-the-last-word-in-the-string-using-javascript

Comment: i got solution using below statements:                                                          var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
                        str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
                        alert(str);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
    var str = " i am from Tamil nadu.";
    var res = str.split(" ");  //split by space
    res.pop();  //remove last element
    alert(res.join(" ") + ".");  //join back together
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this solution:

```
 var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
 str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
 alert(str);
```

Comment: This does not produce the output you put in the question, where you had the full stop (point) at the end of the phrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` by space between words, `slice` the last part off and `join` everything together again. And all in one single line. ;)

```js
var str = "i am from Tamil nadu.";
var my = str.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");

console.log(my);
```

If there always is a `.` at the end, and you want to keep it, you could use regex or something. But when there always is a dot, I would just append them again and not gonna try anything more complex.

```js
var str = "i am from Tamil nadu.";
var my = str.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + ".";

console.log(my);
```

Or you can do a check afterwards too.

```js
var str = "i am from Tamil nadu.";
var my = str.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");

if( str.trim().substr(-1) === "." ) {
    my += ".";
}

console.log(my);
```