# Change background according to last word in hyperlink text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say you have an image representing a hyperlink like (2nd edit to show more):

```html
<a href="https://companysite.com/strawberry-red"><img 
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Spacer.gif"></a>
```

What I want is a script that would switch the image out in accordance with the last word in the hyperlink.

Example: strawberry-**red**, raspberry-**blue**, apple-**green**

Possible CSS: .**red**, .**blue**, .**green**

This might also be done by making a blank box and just simply defining background-image with a script, supported by CSS for the URLs.

This seems relatively easy. Just haven't found a resource and feel like it should be there for people in the future.

It's somewhat similar to [how to remove the last word in the string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323182/how-to-remove-the-last-word-in-the-string-using-javascript/9323309#9323309), just a few more steps.

**EDIT:** Though I haven't seen a spacer.gif in years, this works. Now the background-image or background-color could be defined by CSS. It being an image may be unnecessary. Now it's as if it's not even there!

Comment: 'Switch out the image'... how? The goal of your question is not at all clear.

Comment: By **switch out**, I mean that the placeholder image would be replaced by the corresponding class's background-image in CSS. A placeholder image may be unnecessary. Just how I saw it originally.

Comment: What class? You only have a `href` on the element...?

Comment: I guess the last word would define the class and the class would define the image. Christiaan's almost got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a background based on the last part of an element's class attribute value, you can use the [`[attr$=value]` CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> Represents elements with an attribute name of *attr* whose value is suffixed (followed) by *value*.

Adapting the markup from your example, you could approach it like:

```css
a.color[href$="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}
a.color[href$="green"] {
  background-color: green;
}
a.color[href$="blue"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<a class="color" href="https://companysite.com/strawberry-red">Red</a>
<a class="color" href="https://companysite.com/apple-green">Green</a>
<a class="color" href="https://companysite.com/raspberry-blue">Blue</a>
```

You could also set a background image with this approach instead of just a color.

Comment: Wow! Was not aware of this!

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over all `<a />` tags (or selectively by adding a predefined className) and get the last word from the `href` attribute.

Then add the last word to the classList of the first child element. This is just an example, as I'm not sure how you would "switch" the containing image.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(function(element) {
  var hrefWords = element.getAttribute('href').split('-');
  var lastWord = hrefWords.pop();
  
  element.firstChild.classList.add(lastWord);
});
```

```css
.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com/strawberry-red"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
<a href="example.com/raspberry-blue"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
<a href="example.com/apple-green"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
<a href="example.com/strawberry-red"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
<a href="example.com/raspberry-blue"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
<a href="example.com/apple-green"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/143/200/300.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: The goal would be if the background-image was assigned according to the last word in the link. This would be a situation like having images of cloth swatches. The JS might be better written a little more specific to a div. This is pretty close!