# How to remove part of string that is in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string from which I want to remove the last parentheses "(bob)". So far I use this code to return the value within these parentheses:

```js
const str = "Hello my name is (john) (doe) (bob)";
const result = str.split('(').pop().split(')')[0];
console.log(result);
```

How would I be able to return the string without these last parentheses?

Comment: So the result is `"Hello my name is (john) (doe) bob"` ?

Comment: Or the result is `"Hello my name is (john) (doe)"`?

Comment: the result is: "bob" I want the result to be "Hello my name is (john) (doe)"

Comment: Judging by that last comment of yours, it looks like you also want the result to remove the whitespace.  Is that true?  What if it's `Hello (bob) world`?  Do you want to fix up the double-whitespace that would otherwise remain if you just removed `(bob)`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'Hello my name is (john) (doe) (bob)';
const lastIdxS = str.lastIndexOf('(');

console.log(str.slice(0, lastIdxS).trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: [How to remove the last word in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323182/how-to-remove-the-last-word-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Possibly not the cleanest solution, but if you always want to remove the text behind last parentheses, it will work.

```js
   var str = "Hello my name is (john) (doe) (bob)";
   var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("(");

   str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
   console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the last occurrence of the parentthesis, and replace with capture group 1 that contains all that comea before it:

```
^(.*)\([^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WLUPuk/1)